# How to make two computers connected to a switch but in the different VLANs ping each other?

Tags: routing, switch, vtp

Here is my topology:

[image: Network]

PC3 - VLAN 10

PC0, PC4 - VLAN 20

The switch connected to a router is a Server Switch in VTP. The other two are clients.

I know about router on the stick and PC3 and PC4 can ping each other. I have a question about PC3 to PC0 connection. It just doesn't work.

Is it because the switch doesn't have a connection to a router and directs the packet only to the correct port by MAC? I guess I don't understand the mechanics enough.

What can be done to make the two PCs ping each other? I know it's not what VLANs are for but it just bothers me. Do they need their own router?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have configured the default gateway for PC0.
More information is needed to solve your scenario here (Configurations of the switch and the IP addresses assigned to the router, PCs)

Answer (score 1):

1- Can PC3 and PC0 and ping R2 successfully ?

2- Did you assign interface 0/24 (PC3) on S2 to VLAN 10 properly ?

```
S2(config)#interface fastEthernet 0/24
S2(config-if)#switchport access vlan 10
S2(config-if)#no shutdown
```

3- Did you assign interface 0/23 (PC0) on S2 to VLAN 20 properly ?

```
S2(config)#interface fastEthernet 0/23
S2(config-if)#switchport access vlan 20
S2(config-if)#no shutdown
```

4- have you configured Iner-VLAN on R2 properly ?

Assume:

```
- 172.17.1.1 /24 is our R2 network
- 172.17.10.1/24 is our Vlan 10
- 172.17.20.1/24 is our Vlan 20
- 172.17.99.1/24 is our Vlan 99 (management)
```

R2 Configuration:

```
R2(config)#interface fastEthernet 0/0
R2(config-if)#no shutdown

R2(config-if)#interface fastEthernet 0/0.1
R2(config-subif)#encapsulation dot1Q 1
R2(config-subif)#ip address 172.17.1.1 255.255.255.0

R2(config-if)#interface fastEthernet 0/0.10
R2(config-subif)#encapsulation dot1Q 10
R2(config-subif)#ip address 172.17.10.1 255.255.255.0

R2(config-if)#interface fastEthernet 0/0.20
R2(config-subif)#encapsulation dot1Q 20
R2(config-subif)#ip address 172.17.20.1 255.255.255.0

R2(config-if)#interface fastEthernet 0/0.99
R2(config-subif)#encapsulation dot1Q 99 native
R2(config-subif)#ip address 172.17.99.1 255.255.255.0
```

5- Finally did you assign the Gateway on PC3 and PC0 properly ?

based on IP addresses mentioned above:

PC3:

```
IP Address......................: 172.17.10.10
Subnet Mask.....................: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway.................: 172.17.10.1
```

PC0:

```
IP Address......................: 172.17.20.10
Subnet Mask.....................: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway.................: 172.17.20.1
```

Comment: Usually you would want to set your single-vlan ports (Fa0/23-24) to `switchport mode access` as well.